# How can I change file name color in search dialog in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Please see the red rectangle on the screenshot. WebStorm version 2023.1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This color is defined by the IDE Theme and cannot be changed easily (only by creating your own custom theme as a plug-in).

There is a related issue about the file name color, [feel free to vote](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164958/Find-in-Path-Foreground-Color-for-Duplicates-Not-Legible).